# Why did I get an warning when calculating matrix multiplication of a grid and a vector in Python?

Tags: numpy

I have the following code of calculating the multiplication of a grid and a vector:

```
import numpy as np
Grid = np.ogrid[0:512, 0:512, 0:256]
Vec = np.array([1, 2, 3])
res = Vec @ Grid
```

The warning was:

```
<stdin>:1: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray.
```

Why did the warning happen and how should I remove it in a good way?

Comment: both the reason (Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences is deprecated) and the workaround (specify 'dtype=object') are given in the warning. So what exactly is your question. Can't you do so as proposed?

Comment: @Stef I have a `Grid` as defined above. The coordinates of the nodes in the `Grid` is `A`. `A` is a (3, 512*512*256) matrix, and I want to calculate `Vec @ A`.

Comment: @Stef How to specify 'dtype=object' in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the warning is that `Grid` is a list of differently shaped arrays (`(512, 1, 1)`, `(1, 512, 1)`, and `(1, 1, 256)`). You can silence the warning by specifying the `dtype` as `object`:

```
Vec @ np.array(Grid, dtype=object)
```

The result is a `(512, 512, 256)` shaped 3D array.

Answer (score 1):

This post is longer than I initially intended, but I was curious about the performance of a `ogrid` versus `mgrid` approach.

As noted, `ogrid` creates a list of array that differ in shape:

```
In [67]: o=np.ogrid[0:3,0:2,0:4]; [1,2,3]@np.array(o,object)
    ...: 
Out[67]: 
array([[[ 0,  3,  6,  9],
        [ 2,  5,  8, 11]],

       [[ 1,  4,  7, 10],
        [ 3,  6,  9, 12]],

       [[ 2,  5,  8, 11],
        [ 4,  7, 10, 13]]])

In [68]: o
Out[68]: 
[array([[[0]],
 
        [[1]],
 
        [[2]]]),
 array([[[0],
         [1]]]),
 array([[[0, 1, 2, 3]]])]
```

`@` works with object dtype arrays, but uses slower code, not the fast BLAS.

`mgrid` makes an array, which can be used in `@` with a suitable transpose (to put the sum-of-products dimension 2nd to the last:

```
In [69]: m=np.mgrid[0:3,0:2,0:4];
    ...: [1,2,3]@m.transpose(1,2,0,3)
Out[69]: 
array([[[ 0,  3,  6,  9],
        [ 2,  5,  8, 11]],

       [[ 1,  4,  7, 10],
        [ 3,  6,  9, 12]],

       [[ 2,  5,  8, 11],
        [ 4,  7, 10, 13]]])

In [71]: m.shape
Out[71]: (3, 3, 2, 4)
```

timings

```
In [72]: timeit o=np.ogrid[0:3,0:2,0:4]; [1,2,3]@np.array(o,object)
70.5 µs ± 5.04 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)

In [73]: timeit m=np.mgrid[0:3,0:2,0:4]; [1,2,3]@m.transpose(1,2,0,3)
60.9 µs ± 77.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

Separating out the grid generation step, shows the comparative speed of the two kinds of `matmul`:

```
In [74]: %%timeit o=np.ogrid[0:3,0:2,0:4]
    ...: [1,2,3]@np.array(o,object)
28.3 µs ± 103 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)

In [75]: %%timeit m=np.mgrid[0:3,0:2,0:4]; 
    ...: [1,2,3]@m.transpose(1,2,0,3)
8.35 µs ± 146 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
```

With your larger grid, the comparative advantage of `ogrid` is much greater:

```
In [76]: timeit o=np.ogrid[0:512, 0:512, 0:256]; [1,2,3]@np.array(o,object)
254 ms ± 5.66 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [77]: timeit m=np.mgrid[0:512, 0:512, 0:256]; [1,2,3]@m.transpose(1,2,0,3)
3.74 s ± 193 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

`ogrid` for this size is only 42.2 µs, while `mgrid` is 2.39 s. That means the object @ step is 234 ms, while the higher dimensional float @ is  1.23 s.

Most object dtype math is done at list comprehension speeds.  So the `@` is effectively:

```
In [88]: sum([x*oo for x,oo in zip([1,2,3],o)])
Out[88]: 
array([[[ 0,  3,  6,  9],
        [ 2,  5,  8, 11]],

       [[ 1,  4,  7, 10],
        [ 3,  6,  9, 12]],

       [[ 2,  5,  8, 11],
        [ 4,  7, 10, 13]]])

In [89]: timeit sum([x*oo for x,oo in zip([1,2,3],o)])
18.6 µs ± 186 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)

In [90]: o=np.ogrid[0:512, 0:512, 0:256]  
In [91]: timeit sum([x*oo for x,oo in zip([1,2,3],o)])
227 ms ± 22 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

So these speeds are basically the same as the `object` matmul.